# Why does Range(x) select a cell that shouldn't be in my range?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am pretty new to VBA, and I'm having some trouble understanding how Range works.

Above, I am trying to learn how to use loops to select cells that contain a particular value, and then store all of those chosen cells in a range object.  When I debug.print the MyRange.Address, I get a printout of the cells that contain the searched for value, as expected.  However, when I try to iterate through MyRange one cell at a time by typing, for example, "MyRange(2).Address", I get unexpected cells that do not contain the value I was searching for.

What's going on here?  I thought MyRange would be a list of the cell objects that contain my searched for value, but it seems to contain more than that.

```
Sub FindValues2()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim Cell As Object

 'Check every cell in the range for matching criteria.
For Each Cell In Range("A1:B11")
    If Cell.Value = "a" Then
        If MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)
        Else
            Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Range(Cell.Address))
        End If
    End If
Next
 'Select the new range of only matching criteria
Debug.Print MyRange.Address(1)


End Sub
```

Comment: You want to work with `Range.Areas`.

Comment: Also - please post your code also as text, not just a screenshot.

Comment: `Range(cell.Address)` -> more simply `cell`.

Comment: I'm afraid that your active sheet is not the one where you intend to process the range. Try using the sheet object for your range definition. `Dim sh As Worksheet`  `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet")`   And then use `For each Cell in sh.Range("A1:B11")`.

Comment: @BigBen   Thanks for StackOverflow format advice, fixed.

I'm having trouble implementing your cell.Address suggestion.

Comment: Everywhere you have `Range(Cell.Address)`, replace it with `Cell`.

Comment: @FaneDuru  Thank you for the suggestion  If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting this code is executing on a different worksheet other than the one I am looking at.  I am certain that that is not the case.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but personally I'd qualify that you want to loop through each cell in `Range("A1:B11")` and not say, `Row`, or `Column`:  `For Each Cell In Range("A1:B11").Cells`

Comment: @BruceWayne - the `.Cells` is redundant.

Comment: @BigBen   Ahah right of course, thank you.  Code looks cleaner.  Problem still persists, however.

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, you want to work with `Range.Areas`.

Comment: @BigBen - Ah, thanks for confirming. The whole "Explicit is better than implicit" form Python leaks in to my VBA sometimes... :P

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` and also `dimension` your `variables`

Comment: @BigBen  Thank you.  Still very new to this, feels different from the few other languages I've experienced, and I'm having difficulty.  "Debug.Print MyRange.Areas" doesn't work.  I assume you mean to use Areas somewhere else, but reading through the documentation of this Range property I can't quite figure out where.
 
EDIT: AHAH!  Nevermind got it!  "Debug.Print MyRange.Areas(2).Address"

Answer (score 1):

Use "Debug.Print MyRange.Areas(2).Address" instead.  Thank you @BigBen!